# Html <div class="row"> not centering

Tags: html, css

First I'd like to say that I know very little about coding.

In this website I made http://academiadae.com, I added two small divs at each side, so I could get a div class="6u" centered.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="3u"></div>
    <div class="6u"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
    <div class="3u"></div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to get it centered without the need for the other divs?
I tried making different elements =center in the CSS, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: All you have to do is add the style "margin:auto" to the 6u class, 
notice that this won't work if it's currently floating

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your are using as class `6u` which will not be selected. A CSS name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z) to use it as an CSS selector. You can check this [page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) for any reference.

Second if you want to have the a single div centered you could apply this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item6u">
  test
  </div>
</div>
```

Where there is only one div with a class name that starts with a letter.
For you CSS you need to set the width of the div and like @Sprazer told you need to set the margin:

```
.row{
   background-color:yellow;
}
.item6u{
   background-color:red; 
   width:50%; //changed to 50% percentage as wawa suggested
   margin:0 auto; 
   text-align:center;
}
```

See code here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mkojnqpy/1/).

Comment: I think the `6u` doesn't stand for `600px` but `50%` as a lot of grid systems use 12 columns. therefore, I'd suggest to change the `width:600px;` to `width:50%` (+1 for pointing out that a css class can't start with a numeric character)

Comment: _“First of all, your are using as class `6u` this not allowed”_ – first of all, you’re wrong here. `6u` is a perfectly valid class name in HTML. (That you need to escape it properly, if you want to use the CSS class selector to select an element with that class, is a different issue.)

Comment: @CBroe yup you are right. Thanks for your comment. I modified my answer.

Comment: But when I remove float:left; two columns in the same row stops working.

Comment: @user3677878 you said: "_help me to get it centered without the need for the other divs_" if you remove the other divs and you only have 1 div you do not need any floating properties. Of course you can add to the `.item6u` class the floating property.

Comment: Sorry, you know I meant blank divs.
I added the floating property, but now it's aligned to the left again.

Comment: @user3677878 Can you show me what your situation is? Perhaps in JSFiddle?. EDIT. When I look at your website try to add this: `margin: 0 auto` to your class: `.\36 u, .\36 u\24 {
    width: 50%;
    clear: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

Answer (score -1):

So, you currently have something like: HTML

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="3u">
                </div>
                <div class="6u">
                    <img src="images/logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="3u">
                </div>
            </div>
```

and CSS:

```
div.6u{
width: 50%;
clear: none;
float:left;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

You need to change this to HTML:

```
<div class="row>
   <div class="6u">
    ...contents of the div here...
   </div>
</div>
```

and CSS (note: do remove float:left, otherwise it will not work):

```
div.6u{
width:50%;
clear:none;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
```